# std::thread works in cygwin but not in MinGw

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin, mingw, stdthread

So I decided to give c++ a try today. I downloaded MinGw and the g++ compiler that comes with it. I decided to test the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(foo);
    t1.join();
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I then tried to compile it on the command line using the following line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

Which works for hello world. This time however, it gave me this error:

`error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'`

I tried the exact same code using the g++ provided by cygwin, and it works. So why doesn't it work in MinGw? Is it outdated or something? I want to compile stuff using c++11 and c++14 like on the cygwin terminal, but outside of the cygwin environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MinGW-w64 (or rather GCC on windows) needs to be compiled with posix thread support if you want to use `std::thread`, presumably you downloaded a build with native windows threads.

Check out the mingw-builds folders targeting [64 bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) or [32 bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) and pick a version with posix threads. You'll also need to choose the exception handling method, if you don't have a reason to choose otherwise then stick with the GCC defaults of seh for 64 bit and dwarf for 32.

Comment: I had this issue the other day... The following link could be useful in your answer http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw-w64/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.3.0/threads-posix/

Comment: @NathanielBrough It's not usually a good idea to link to concrete versions of things in a SO answer, it can lead to people downloading old software down the line.

Comment: @NathanielBrough Are you saying that it's definitely the case that MinGw is outdated and that by installing MinGw-64, it will solve this problem? Also, are they the same thing, or just updates of one anohter?

Comment: @user3685285 No I recently had an up to date version of mingw-w64 that only supported win32 threads. Choose a version of mingw that supports posix threads as the answer above has explained. **Note:** the current mingw-w64 installer from sourceforge gives you the option to download a posix version in a drop down box.

Comment: @user3685285 even gcc 4.8.1 has the header file `threads` but the compiler has to be built to support `std::thread`. So it is not just about having an outdated compiler.

Comment: @user3685285 MinGW has only had sporadic updates over the last few years, the latest experimental versions I can see on their sourceforge download page is for GCC 4.9.3, switch to MinGW-w64 you won't regret it.

Comment: thanks guys, all super useful comments for a beginner like me. I installed MinGw-64 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this in linux (cross-compiling).

This compiles ok,

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix -std=c++11 threads.cpp -lwinpthread
```

this does not

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++-win32 -std=c++11 threads.cpp -lwinpthread
```

The difference between the compilers is `--enable-threads=win32` vs. `--enable-threads=posix` option used when the compilers were built. `g++ -v` should show what was used.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too much of a c++ noob to understand what you mean. I'm using windows. What's cross-compiling? What should I do to enable posix, or do I need a linux machine?

Comment: @user3685285 Sorry if I confused you. I just didn't have a windows computer with right kind of compiler version at hand to confirm my suspicions. With a cross-compiler I can compile windows applications using a linux machine (a proper answer would take too long, google should tell).