# gcc 6.2.0 thread is not a member of std

Tags: multithreading, c++11, gcc, stl

**Program:**

```
#include <thread>

int main(void)
{
    std::thread t;
    return 0;
}

test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:6:5: error: ‘thread’ is not a member of ‘std’
    std::thread t;
    ^~~
```

**GCC info:**

```
$ g++ test.cpp -H
. /home/nathan/development/toolchain/gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/6.2.0/thread

$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/nathan/development/toolchain/gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc/configure --prefix=/home/nathan/development/toolchain/gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --enable-threads=posix --enable-libstdcxx-threads
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.0 (GCC)
```

Using other parts of STL work just fine, it is only `thread` that fails. Am I
missing something? When configured, GCC picks up the threading model.

**Edit 1**

Recompiled GCC with `--enable-threads`. Still produces same error.

**Edit 2**

Recompiled GCC with `--enable-libstdcxx-threads`. Still produces same error.

**Edit 3**

Recompiled GCC with `--enable-threads=posix`. Still produces same error.

**Edit 4**

Wanted to make clear that I was building using the repo on branch `gcc-6_2_0-release`.

Comment: You probably have built gcc without threading support for C++. Try `g++.exe -dM -E -x c++ -std=c++11 test.cpp | egrep '_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS|_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1`. If you don't see both defines, your build has no threading support. No idea if `--enable-threads` is still needed.

Comment: I only see `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1 1`. Guess I rebuild with `--enable-threads`. Why is this not the default in 2016?

Comment: @n.m. I just finished building with `--enable-threads` and I still get the same the same error. Am I missing something else?

Comment: No idea. Grep the build logs for messages about threads.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `--enable-threads=posix`? I think this is mentioned in the `gcc` configuration documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

Comment: @ChrisBeck Just tried to compile with that as well, no help.

Comment: I think you need to do what n.m. said, and grep through the build logs for messages about threads. It is most likely skipping the threads build for some reason. Or, you aren't really doing the full gcc build -- note that there are several steps I recall, a configuration step, then a build ancilllary libraries step, then a rebuild the main compiler. If you skip the ancillary libraries step then you might not get thread, bignum, atomic, etc. You should read the full gcc build instructions and verify that you are following line for line.

Comment: @ChrisBeck I've followed about every instruction and option that I know of. I believe the "ancillary libraries" you refer to are cloog, gmp, isl, mpc, and mpfr. I have those as well. Seems weird it unpacks it into the C++ include section, also picks it up when `#include <thread>` is used, but says it isn't a part of standard.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are *not* compiling at C++98 standard? You could try dumping the value of the `__cplusplus` macro

Comment: That's the first reason that comes to mind that `#include <thread> ` might work but `std::thread` isn't there. There are pretty common related bugs people report when building mingw, see here for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847804/stdthread-works-in-cygwin-but-not-in-mingw I never saw this issue happen to someone building a native c++ compiler on linux though.

Comment: @ChrisBeck I've tried compiling with `-std=c++11` and 14 to no avail. Yeah, the only results I get from Google are all the mingw problems too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying multiple times to build using the repo source, I eventually gave up, and compiled using the released tarballs from a GNU mirror. Not sure what options would have made the difference from what is in the repo vs what is released, but I simply used:

`--enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib`

and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Good to know, I guess I will make note to always use the release tarballs... you could try looking and see if they have "releasing gcc" instructions somewhere? there may be indeed be some extra preparation steps like copying code over from other repos or something.